# why the lock on a file is not deleted when the process which created the lock is killed?

Tags: c++, linux

We have Socket Server which creates a file using open() in /tmp directory and locks it using flock() with flags LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB. we will check the return value of flock() and if error is EWOULDBLOCK, we are exiting from Socket Server. If the return value is success, we are exiting. This is to make sure that only one Socket Server is running always.

But we observed that when the process which created the lock is killed, the lock is not getting removed on the file. So subsequent tries to start the Socket Server (when existing Socket Server process died) are failing because of this reason. Can any on please let me know why the lock on the file is not removed when the process which created the lock is killed and is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that all conditions described in `man 2 flock` are met? In particular, are you sure that there are no forked processes which still hold file descriptor in opened state? (you may use `lsof` or `fuser` to check this)

Comment: @gudok After flock check, we are using fork() to create child processes. But those processes are not using this file.

Comment: Show us the code. We can't debug what we can't see. And since by definition you don't know where the problem is you are probably leaving out the critical points. If you `fork` after opening then the child processes need to `close` the file before the lock will be released.

Comment: They will still inherit the file handle and all locks nonetheless, unless they specifically close their copy of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its beacuse you are not closing the file descriptor when the process crush.
flock doc: https://linux.die.net/man/2/flock

> the lock is released either by an explicit LOCK_UN operation on any of these duplicate descriptors, or when all such descriptors have been closed

the solution for this is to wait for signal 15 (kill) and do somthing.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal

or maybe run the server as thread which and when it close or crush close the file discriptor(threads share the memory).

Comment: This is not robust. It won't help if process is SIGKILLed. Proper solution was mentioned before by @IanM_Matrix1.

Comment: @gudok correct. But how application get chance to close the file descriptors if the process dies unexpectedly.

Comment: All fork()ed processed must close this file descriptor immediately after they were created, not parent process.

Comment: @gudok I understood. But only question is we are creating daemon process (so parent process will be closed) and if I close the file descriptor in daemon process, will the lock be released?

Comment: Manual page mentions the conditions: lock is removed if 1) either it is explicitly unlocked by flock(fd, LOCK_UN) by _any_ of the processes (doesn't matter whether it is parent or child) or 2) its file descriptors are closed in _all_ processes (when process dies, its file descriptors are closed automatically).

Comment: i added an update,  i meant to run the server as thread and then you will have the fd in both the thread and his creator.

Answer (score 4):

When you fork, the child process inherits a duplicate of the file descriptor.
The lock will not be released until all duplicates of the file descriptor is closed.

To avoid the problem, the child process should close the file descriptor after fork() returns.

If every time you fork() the child calls exec(), then you can avoid this by using O_CLOEXEC in the open() flags parameter.  This will cause the child's duplicate file descriptor to be closed automatically when exec() is called by the child process.  See 'man open' for more on O_CLOEXEC.

Answer (score 0):

The lock was auto released while process killed, I have test on Ubuntu21.04+GCC10.3.0。